# 1C ошибка при обращении к общему модулю

Tags: 1с

Пытаюсь вынести функцию в общие модули и пробую на элементарном примере.

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Команда1(Команда)
    ВыполнитьЗапросНаСервере();
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Процедура ВыполнитьЗапросНаСервере()
    a = ОбщиеФункции.ЗаполнитьТаблицуФормы();
        сообщить(a);
КонецПроцедуры
```

В общем модуле я создала модуль `общиеФункции` с функцией
`ЗаполнитьТаблицуФормы()`

```
Функция ЗаполнитьТаблицуФормы()экспорт
рез = 1+1;
возврат рез;
КонецФункции
```

На общих функциях стоит галочка Сервер и ВызовСервера

Ошибка:

> {Форма.Форма.Форма(17,6)}: Переменная не определена (ОбщиеФункции)
>       a = <>ОбщиеФункции.ЗаполнитьТаблицуФормы();

Comment: Как не смешно это звучит, но возможно ошибка в орфографии. Проверьте название общего модуля.

Comment: @1C_Man ваш ответ не является ответом на вопрос, укажите явно, где вы видите ошибку в орфографии.

Answer (score 2):

Странная ошибка: по описанию создал пустую базу, всё работает, см. [пример работоспособности в 8.3.7](https://yadi.sk/d/C1HdCAVdmksZB).

Также у Вас написано, что ошибка возникает в строке 17:

> {Форма.Форма.Форма(17,6)}

но код

`a = ОбщиеФункции.ЗаполнитьТаблицуФормы();`

находится не в 17-й строке. Видимо, Вы привели не весь текст модуля формы.

Уточните, пожалуйста, что за форма или выложите выгрузку базы, на которой воспроизводится ошибка, а также релиз платформы.